# Any way to get stable/consistent FPS form kinect?

Tags: kinect, openni

I am trying to record kinect files in .oni format, that I will later try to synchronize with other sensors. As such, it is very important that I get consistent fps, even if some frames are repeats.

From what I can see now, WaitAndUpdateAll does not guarantee that the frame rate is consistent. I will be recording for several minutes (20+), so I need to make sure there is no drift!

Does anyone know if it's possible to lock down the fps of the recording, and if not, how stable the recording fps of the kinect is? Thanks!

---

After some investigation of this issue, I put together the following write up on the topic:

http://denislantsman.com/?p=50

Putting it here so interested people can find it and not have to wrestle with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be to go with the PCL libary since the developers also work together with the ROS team where they also have to sync sensors a lot. But be warned I wasn't able capture XYZRGB clouds at 30 FPS on windows 7. If you only need XYZ to be captured you should be fine. Worst case you have to time stamp and sync all your data by yourself.